# Can we decide which release pipeline to run after pushing the VS tabular project (*.bim)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a VS solution with multiple tabular projects 【one project means one model(.bim)】.
Our goal is to use Azure DevOps Pipeline to deploy those models to Azure Analysis Service.

Now, we already create the Release Pipeline. But there is a question, when the code has been changed, all the stages will be triggered.(We Deploy One Model in One Stage)
However, we hope if only one .bim file have been changed, the related stages will be triggered, not all stages.

How Can I reach the goal? Many Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-the-box method to achieve your goal for the time being.

In Release Pipeline, it only supports setting trigger conditions based on branch.

[image]

> How Can I reach the goal?

**Workaround:**

You could use PowerShell Task to Rest API([Commits - Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)) to get the changed file path via commitid.  Then you could determine if the stage will continue to run based on the result.

Here is an example:

You could add the following script to each stage based  on the actual situation:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName]/{Projectname}/_apis/git/repositories/$(BUILD.DEFINTIONID)/commits/$(BUILD.SOURCEVERSION)/changes"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

$count = 0


Foreach($c in $response.changes)
{
  
  if ($c.item.path -ne "/file path /xxxx/xx/xx.bim")
  {
     $count ++
     
  }

 
 
}

if($count -eq 0 )
{

 
   Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Canceled;]DONE"
  
}

else
{
   echo "The changes contain the file"

}
```

On the other hand, I suggest that you could create a suggestion tikcet in [Our UserVoice Site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to report this feature.